# Perl - Having trouble using MIME::Lite with authentication to send emails

Tags: perl, email, authentication, smtp, mime

I'm trying to send emails out using `MIME::Lite` with authentication.

Here's the code snippet I am trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;
use lib '/theannealing.com/perl/';
use MIME::Lite;
use MIME::Base64;
use Authen::SASL;

my $recipient       =   'recipient@email.com';
my $mailman         =   'sender@email.com';
my $cc_recipient    =   'ccrecipient@email.com';
my $subject         =   'Subject';
my $email_message   =   "Message";

my ($user,$pass) = ("username","password");

MIME::Lite->send('smtp','smtp.server:port',AuthUser=>$user, AuthPass=>$pass);
my $email = new MIME::Lite(From => $mailman,To => $recipient,Cc => $cc_recipient,Subject => $subject,Data => "Data",Type => "multipart/mixed"); 
$email->attach(Type => 'TEXT', Data => "$email_message");
$email->send();
```

When I execute the script, I get this error message:

`Cannot find a SASL Connection library at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Net/SMTP.pm line 143`

I tried searching the error message and couldn't find any worth-while explanations and/or solutions to the problem with relevance to usage with `MIME::Lite`

Does anyone know what's wrong or what's producing that error message?

---

**UPDATE**
Emailing via php using the `mail()` function works fine from a web browser, but does not work from the command line

Comment: Which version of Net::SMTP do you have installed?

Comment: I'm not using `Net::SMTP`, I'm using `MIME::Lite`

Comment: Yes, but your error is **clearly** originating from Net::SMTP.

Comment: ok, well thats a start.... i guess one of the `.pm` files is calling to `Net::SMTP` but there is no custom code in place that uses `Net::SMTP`

Comment: Do you have Authen::SASL::Perl installed? Which version of Authen::SASL do you have?

Comment: no to the first question and I installed it from CPAN today so I'm guessing the latest version - 2.15

Comment: Authen::SASL::Perl is included into Authen::SASL distribution.

Comment: Do perl -MAuthen::SASL::Perl -e"print Authen::SASL::Perl->VERSION()"

Comment: `Can't locate Authen/SASL/Perl.pm in @INC`.... I saved the `.pm` file manually within that path that I'm using on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinstall Authen::SASL - it was installed incorrectly. Do this as root from command line:

```
cpan GBARR/Authen-SASL-2.15.tar.gz
```